# Redundancy in solutions to a Diophantine equation.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

[image]
Here, they write the solution with both 
(4d,d) and (12d,3d) and similarly (d,d) and (5d,5d).

Aren't these two sets redundant as the second can be expressed as the first as d varies over the integers?

The solution I obtained was (a,a) ,(4a,a) and (19a,a); $$a\in\mathbb{Z}$$.
Is this correct?

Comment: I am referring to problem number 3, in case it is unclear.

Comment: It would be better if you told people which year's RMO this is from, and included the link.